# React loses props inside array

Tags: reactjs

I'm using `react-contexify` for my project.

If I just render children inside `<ContextMenu>` everything works great

```
const onClick = ({ event, ref, data, dataFromProvider }) => console.log(event);

const MyAwesomeMenu = () => (
   <ContextMenu id='menu_id'>
     <Item onClick={onClick}>1</Item>
     <Item onClick={onClick}>1</Item>
   </ContextMenu>
);
```

`Console` returns `MouseEvent`, which is fine.

If I render items using another function inside `map` `console` return empty object `{}`

```
const SingleItem = () => (
   <Item onClick={onClick}>Menu item</Item>
);

const ItemArray = () => (
  [1,2,3].map((item, index) => {
    return <SingleItem key={index} />
  })
)

const MyAwesomeMenu = () => (
   <ContextMenu id='menu_id'>
     {ItemArray()}
   </ContextMenu>
);
```

I don't understand why `event` is empty in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parent component onClick event will not work in the child component implicitly. You would need to pass the props:

```
const onClick = ({ event, ref, data, dataFromProvider }) => console.log(event);

const MyAwesomeMenu = () => (
   <ContextMenu id='menu_id'>
     <ItemArray onClick={onClick} />
   </ContextMenu>
);

const ItemArray = (props) => (
  [1,2,3].map((item, index) => {
    return <SingleItem key={index} {...props} />
  })
)

const SingleItem = (props) => (
   <Item {...props}>Menu item</Item>
);
```

Notice, I have used `{...props}` to pass the properties of the parent component which indicates that it will get all the props of parent component. If you wish only to pass the onClick props, then you would pass like this:

```
onClick={props.onClick}
```